# Kivy Multiselect Spinner: 2nd time adding an item, spinner behaves oddly

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

*Kivy 1.10.0* and using a kv file for my Kivy language.

*Python 3.6*

I have an app that works with mysql3. One page of the app allows me to add an 'flash card' to the database. One of the form elements when adding the flash card uses a Multiselect Spinner to add one or more tags, this data is then saved to the database. The first time I access this page, I can use the spinner and add everything as expected. Then if I go back to try to add a second flash card, even though the form is cleared and everything looks exactly as it does the first time I add a flash card, the spinner acts strangly. Data seems to be getting stored somewhere, as can be seen in the third gif, and somehow loaded back into the spinner data. (The problem is the same for the 'decks' spinner.)

This gif shows it working properly the first time I add a new card:

[image]

This gif shows the second time I add a new card (this happens regardless of what I do between adding the two cards, except quitting the app entirely):

[image]

This gif shows that data seems to be retained:

[image]

Because the code is long, I will add only what I believe relevant. If something is missing, please let me know and I'll add it right away.

```
class NewFlashCardScreen(Screen):
    data = DictProperty({})
    data_fc_tag_ids = DictProperty({})
    data_fc_deck_ids = DictProperty({})
    __events__ = ('on_submit',)
    fc_tag_spinner_list = ListProperty(None)
    fc_deck_spinner_list = ListProperty(None)

    def on_parent(self, widget, parent):
        gd = App.get_running_app()
        self.fc_tag_spinner_list = []
        fc_tag_list = Queries.get_fc_tag_list()
        if len(fc_tag_list) > 0:
            for fc_tag in fc_tag_list:
                self.fc_tag_spinner_list.append(fc_tag[1])
                self.data_fc_tag_ids[fc_tag[1]] = fc_tag[0]
        else:
            self.fc_tag_spinner_list.append("")
        self.fc_deck_spinner_list = []
        fc_deck_list = Queries.get_fc_deck_list()
        if len(fc_deck_list) > 0:
            for fc_deck in fc_deck_list:
                self.fc_deck_spinner_list.append(fc_deck[1])
                self.data_fc_deck_ids[fc_deck[1]] = fc_deck[0]
        else:
            self.fc_deck_spinner_list.append("")

    def get_spinner_lists(self):
        pass

    def on_submit(self, data):
        gd = App.get_running_app()
        self.data['orig'] = gd.glob_dict['orig']
        title = data['fc_title'] if data['fc_title'] else " "
        front = data['fc_front'] if data['fc_front'] else " "
        back = data['fc_back'] if data['fc_back'] else " "
        difficulty = data['fc_difficulty'] if data['fc_difficulty'] else 0
        self.fc_id = MiscFuns.get_id(16)
        try:
            c.execute("""
                        INSERT INTO `tbl_learning_flash_cards` (`fc_id`,`fc_title`,`fc_front`,`fc_back`,`fc_difficulty`)
                        VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
                    """, (self.fc_id, title, front, back, difficulty))
            conn.commit()
        except sqlite3.Error as e:
            print("An error occurred:", e.args[0])


class MultiSelectSpinner(Button):

    dropdown = ObjectProperty(None)
    values = ListProperty([])
    selected_values = ListProperty([])

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.values.clear()
        self.selected_values.clear()
        self.bind(dropdown=self.update_dropdown)
        self.bind(values=self.update_dropdown)
        super(MultiSelectSpinner, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.bind(on_release=self.toggle_dropdown)

    def toggle_dropdown(self, *args):
        if self.dropdown.parent:
            self.dropdown.dismiss()
        else:
            self.dropdown.open(self)

    def update_dropdown(self, *args):
        if not self.dropdown:
            self.dropdown = DropDown()
        values = self.values
        if values:
            if self.dropdown.children:
                self.dropdown.clear_widgets()
            for value in values:
                b = Factory.MultiSelectOption(text=value)
                b.bind(state=self.select_value)
                self.dropdown.add_widget(b)

    def select_value(self, instance, value):
        if value == 'down':
            if instance.text not in self.selected_values:
                self.selected_values.append(instance.text)
        else:
            if instance.text in self.selected_values:
                self.selected_values.remove(instance.text)

    def on_selected_values(self, instance, value):
        if value:
            self.text = ';'.join(value)
        else:
            self.text = ''
```

And the kv file:

```
<NewFlashCardScreen>:
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: 0.1
        Label:
            size_hint_x: 0.2
            text: "Card Title"
            text_size: self.text_size
            valign: 'middle'
        TextInput:
            id: new_fc_title
            multiline: False
            padding_y: [self.height / 2.0 - (self.line_height / 2.0) * len(self._lines), 0]
            text: root.data['fc_title'] if 'fc_title' in root.data else ""
            on_text: root.data['fc_title'] = self.text
        Label:
            size_hint_x: 0.2
            text: "Difficulty"
            text_size: self.text_size
            valign: 'middle'
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: 0.1
        Label:
            size_hint_x: 0.2
            text: "Card Tag(s)"
            text_size: self.text_size
            valign: 'middle'
        BoxLayout:
            MultiSelectSpinner:
                id: new_fc_tag
                text: root.data['fc_tags'] if 'fc_tags' in root.data else "Select tag(s)"
                values: root.fc_tag_spinner_list
                on_text: root.data['fc_tags'] = self.text
            Button:
                size_hint_x: 0.3
                text: "New Tag"
                on_release: lib.Navigation.page_nav(dest='new_flash_card_tag', orig='new_flash_card', edit=False)
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_x: 0.2
            TextInput:
                padding_y: [self.height / 2.0 - (self.line_height / 2.0) * len(self._lines), 0]
                id: new_fc_difficulty
                text: root.data['fc_difficulty'] if 'fc_difficulty' in root.data else "0"
                on_text: root.data['fc_difficulty'] = self.text
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: 0.1
        Label:
            size_hint_x: 0.2
            text: "Card Deck(s)"
            text_size: self.text_size
            valign: 'middle'
        BoxLayout:
            MultiSelectSpinner:
                id: new_fc_deck
                text: root.data['fc_decks'] if 'fc_decks' in root.data else "Select deck(s)"
                values: root.fc_deck_spinner_list
                on_text: root.data['fc_decks'] = self.text
            Button:
                size_hint_x: 0.3
                text: "New Deck"
                on_release: lib.Navigation.page_nav(dest='new_flash_card_deck', orig='new_flash_card', edit=False)
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_x: 0.2
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            size_hint_y: 0.1
            text: "Card Front"
        BoxLayout:
            TextInput:
                id: new_fc_front
                multiline: True
                text: root.data['fc_front'] if 'fc_front' in root.data else ""
                on_text: root.data['fc_front'] = self.text
            RstDocument:
                text: new_fc_front.text
                show_errors: True
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            size_hint_y: 0.1
            text: "Card Back"
        BoxLayout:
            TextInput:
                id: new_fc_back
                multiline: True
                text: root.data['fc_back'] if 'fc_back' in root.data else ""
                on_text: root.data['fc_back'] = self.text
            RstDocument:
                text: new_fc_back.text
                show_errors: True
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: 0.2
        Button:
            text: "Cancel"
            on_release: lib.Navigation.page_nav(dest='prev_page', orig='new_flash_card', edit=False)
        Button:
            text: "Submit"
            on_release: root.dispatch('on_submit', root.data)
```

I've tried clearing the dictionary files, self.data, self.data_fc_tag_ids, and self.data_fc_deck_ids, but that doesn't help.

I have no idea what data is being retained and how to get rid of it. Thank you.

Comment: How did you define `MultiSelectSpinner`? What buttons are you using for the dropdown? You likely just need to reset the state of of the spinner. But it's hard to tell what's going on with the code.

Comment: Since MultiSelectSpinner is a built-in Kivy class, and I'm using a kv file, I didn't even have to import it. I set it with `fc_tag_spinner_list = ListProperty(None)`, set its values then all I had to do was call it from the kv file under the `MultiSelectSpinner:` section. Nothing more.

Comment: I'm sorry, but can't seem to find it. I searched the docs, and nothing returned. Is this newer than 1.10.0? Can you share a link? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for looking Mox. I don't currently have the app on GitHub so I can't share the link but there is nothing more to the section I'm having issues with than what I put in the question. It's using Kivy 1.10.0.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I was looking for MultiSelectSpinner in the source code in Kivy. You said it was built into kivy but I can't find it.

Comment: I feel like an idiot. There is one more (very important) piece of code I left out. I'm new to Kivy and simply trying to put together this app so for this part I used code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36609017/kivy-spinner-widget-with-multiple-selection. I added the additional code, the MultiSelectSpinner(Button) class, to the question. It's not a Spinner, it's actually a combination of dropdown and lists. Sorry...

Answer (score 0):

John Don't woory! I get the solution.. Here is the path: In kv file first we can mention Dropdown widget, under Drop down we will mention check boxes and this is the answer.. Here is the kv file code:

```
DropDown:
                    padding: 0, 0, 0, root.width * 0.4
                    id: dropdown
                    on_select: btn.text = '{}'.format(args[1])

                    GridLayout:
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: 44
                        cols: 2
                        row_default_height: '10dp'
                        Label:
                            id: person
                            text: 'Person'
                            text_size: self.size
                            valign: 'middle'
                        CheckBox:
                            text: 'check me'
                            on_active:
                                root.on_checkbox_active(person.text, self.active)
                    GridLayout:
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: 44
                        cols: 2
                        row_default_height: '10dp'
                        Label:
                            id: vehicle
                            text: 'Vehicle'
                            text_size: self.size
                            valign: 'middle'
                        CheckBox:
                            id: vecle
                            text: 'check me'
                            on_active:
                                root.on_checkbox_active(vehicle.text, self.active)
                    GridLayout:
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: 44
                        cols: 2
                        row_default_height: '10dp'
                        Label:
                            id: aircraft
                            text: 'Air_craft'
                            text_size: self.size
                            valign: 'middle'
                        CheckBox:
                            text: 'check me'
                            on_active:
                                root.on_checkbox_active(aircraft.text, self.active)
```

The .py file:

```
class My_class(BoxLayout):

def on_checkbox_active(checkbox_ref, name, checkbox_value):
    if checkbox_value:
        print('', name, 'is active')
    else:
        print('', name, 'is inactive')
pass
```

Comment: The widget will let you select multiple options under drop down.